# Hadoop data replication block size rate for 1TB of data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 7 data nodes of the following storage sizes:

- datanode 1: 250gb
- datanode 2: 250gb
- datanode 3: 250gb
- datanode 4: 45gb
- datanode 5: 250gb
- datanode 6: 250gb
- datanode 7: 250gb

On data node 4, I have a 1TB of data mounted on /data. So I began a `put` operation (`hadoop fs -put /data /user/hadoop-user/`) on datanode 4. When the storage is exhausted, it continued the operation on the other data nodes with larger storage but the speed is very slow.

Now my questions are:

1. Is there a way to increase the block size rate of the `put` operation? From [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replication+Pipelining), it says "DataNode starts receiving the data in small portions of (4 KB)". That seems too small for a 1TB data. Is there a way to increase this?
2. If I stop the put operation in order to increase the blocksize rate (if any), will it resume from where it stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

- yes - read about `dfs.stream-buffer-size`, `dfs.bytes-per-checksum` and `dfs.client-write-packet-size` - that said the packet itself is larger, and I would be careful with those settings - most probably the problem is somewhere else
- native answer is - no - it will not resume (but look at questions), it won't resume file(s) that were in progress, but it may not overwrite files that are already fully uploaded

Questions:

- what is your network setup?
- what is your replication factor?
- what is your minimal replication factor?
- which version of hadoop is it?
- what does it mean that the speed is slow?
- is the data you want to write as single file or multiple files?
- can you mount the data at multiple nodes?

Additionally:

- you may consider distcp and enforce singe map-only job - with task running on the node with data - which gives you updates and retries etc. (have not tried such scenario myself tho)